# Discord py - edit webhook message embed in 'on_message'

Tags: python, python-3.x, webhooks, discord.py

i have a small problem that i dont know how to fix it. I want to edit a messages embed, that was send by a discord webhook directly if it gets posted. So that's why i use the 'on_message' event for this. In the normal way, you can just fetch the message and than use `msg.edit` but that doesnt work for webhook messages.

How can i edit the message from the webhook directly when it gets posted? I tried to use the api "discord-webhooks" but i couldn't find a solution for that what i want.

I tried this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
##### Netflix-News edit ######
    if message.channel.id == 804484025166856262:
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{title}",
                                  url=f"{lonk}",
                                  description=f"{descfix}",
                                  color=0xe74c3c)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"https://i.imgur.com/4np2bdK.png")
            embed.set_image(url=f"{Thumbnail}")
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{footer}", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/4np2bdK.png")
            
            webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='LINKHERE')
            webhook.embed = embed
            await webhook.edit(sent_webhook)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Webhook.edit` edits the webhook itself, not a message. To edit a message use `Webhook.edit_message`

```py
await webhook.edit_message(message_id, embed=embed)
```

*PS: You didn't define `sent_webhook`*

#### Reference:

- [`Webhook.edit_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook.edit_message)

Comment: i get AttributeError: 'DiscordWebhook' object has no attribute 'edit_message'

Comment: Are you using the official discord.py webhooks? it seems that you're using an external library

Comment: How can i use the default discord webhook? webhook = Webhook.from_url doesnt work too.

Comment: `NameError: name 'Webhook' is not defined`

Comment: I think that pretty much for itself, it's `discord.Webhook.from_url`, next time a bit of thinking and basic problem solving skills would avoid all of this handholding

Comment: Okay thanks, but what should i use for adapter= now?

Comment: You can pass a `discord.AsyncWebhookAdapter`, really depends what library you're using. Take a look at the [examples](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#webhook)